# Altering the current outcome of the model of a generated scaffold

Tags: model, generator, scaffolding, ruby-on-rails-7, railtie

I aim to make some turbo additions to the current scaffold generator. For that i need the plural_model_name in the model. I am looking for a way to alter the output model, generated by the `rails g scaffold` command.

```rb
class <%= singular_model_name %> < ApplicationRecord
  broadcasts to: <%= plural_model_name %>
end
```

Can anyone give me a nudge in the right direction?, I would also be very thankful if some instructions can be given as to in which folder in `/lib/`i am supposed to place the monkey-patched version.

I have been going through nearly all generators [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/f95c0b7e96eb36bc3efc0c5beffbb9e84ea664e4/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails)  but i cannot seem to get a grasp of where the model is taken care of.

Contrary to the model i have successfully been able to alter the [view templates](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/f95c0b7e96eb36bc3efc0c5beffbb9e84ea664e4/railties/lib/rails/generators/erb/scaffold/templates), [view generator](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f95c0b7e96eb36bc3efc0c5beffbb9e84ea664e4/railties/lib/rails/generators/erb/scaffold/scaffold_generator.rb), and [controller template](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f95c0b7e96eb36bc3efc0c5beffbb9e84ea664e4/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/scaffold_controller/templates/controller.rb.tt) and [ScaffoldControllerGenerator](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f95c0b7e96eb36bc3efc0c5beffbb9e84ea664e4/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/scaffold_controller/scaffold_controller_generator.rb) for the scaffold generator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's defined in https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f95c0b7e96eb36bc3efc0c5beffbb9e84ea664e4/activerecord/lib/rails/generators/active_record/model/templates/model.rb.tt

You should be able to add it there

Second, configure your options in https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f95c0b7e96eb36bc3efc0c5beffbb9e84ea664e4/activerecord/lib/rails/generators/active_record/model/model_generator.rb